# Different answers when calling PointToScreen vs CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have a WPF window located at the top left corner of my primary (and only) screen. I want to translate the point  (0,0) in the window to screen coordinates. I believe the following two calls should give me the same result:

**1. This results in (8,8)...**

```
window.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
```

**2. This results in (0,0)...**

```
PresentationSource.FromVisual(window).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform(new Point(0,0));
```

Why?

The 8 pixel difference suggests that the first call considers the window coordinate system to start AFTER the border, while the second considers the window as a whole, including the non client area (resizing borders & toolbar). Is that true?

(edited to remove superfluous detail about DPI settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know about *client area*, right?

First call is useful if you want to find out location of child, put into position (0,0) *of window*, it will be a point *inside client region*. Window border (to not mix up with `Border`) **is not** client region.

The second call, as I see it, is coordinates of *window itself* (including border).

Comment: That makes perfect sense, yes. I was attempting to use call 1, but I got bogged down attempting to compensate for border widths etc from SystemParameters. Call two, as you say, returns the limits of the window handle itself, including all non-client area stuff. Thanks very much.

Comment: In my opinion the last sentence of this answer is wrong.
TransformToDevice just contains the DPI Scale Factor of the monitor, thus a (0,0) is always transformed to (0,0). It does not calculate the Screen coordinates of the logical coordinate (0,0). Correct me if I'm wrong.
I tried to get the screen coordinates of the top left of a window and with (0,0) it does not work.

Comment: @Lumo, not sure what is your problem, perhaps worth to ask a new question then? The OP code is similar to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7046050/1997232).